# How to use SVG clipPath with Pattern via CSS clip-path property?

Tags: css, svg, clip-path

**The initial `SVG` figure with `pattern`:**

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="img-dotted-dots" x="0" y="0" height=".08" width="7.69%">
      <circle cx="2" cy="2" fill="white" r="0.8"></circle>
    </pattern>
    <mask id="img-dotted-mask">
      <rect width="100" height="100" fill="url(#img-dotted-dots)"></rect>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <path d="M0 0 H 100 V 100 H 0 Z" mask="url(#img-dotted-mask)" fill="#1063B1"></path>
</svg>
```

**Need to achieve:**

One instance of the `SVG` figure with `pattern` for refferencing with `CSS` as `clip-path`.

I have tried to create **SVG** `clipPath` element and bind to **CSS** `clip-path` by this way

```css
.figure {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  clip-path: url(#img-dotted-clip-path);
  background-color: #1063B1;
}
```

```html
<div class="figure"></div>

<svg width="0" height="0" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <defs>
    <clipPath
      clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"
      id="img-dotted-clip-path"> 
        <pattern
        patternUnits="objectBoundingBox"
        patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"
        x="0" y="0" height="0.1" width="0.1">
        <circle cx="0" cy="0" fill="white" r="0.5"></circle>
      </pattern>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Nothing happens.
Expected result - the same as the previous snippet.

**For comparing:**

If I use **SVG** `rect` - **CSS** `clip-path` works.
If `pattern` - doesn't

```css
.figure {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  clip-path: url(#img-dotted-clip-path);
  background-color: #1063B1;
}
```

```html
<div class="figure"></div>

<svg width="0" height="0" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <defs>
    <clipPath
      clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"
      id="img-dotted-clip-path"> 
        <rect width="1" height="1"></rect>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only things that are valid inside a clip path are:

- Shape elements (‘circle’, ‘ellipse’, ‘line’, ‘path’, ‘polygon’, ‘polyline’, ‘rect’)
- ‘text’
- ‘use’

Plus you can use animation elements etc to animate the clip path.  However, **only the shapes of those elements are used**.  Effects such as patterns, filters, etc are ignored.

The only way you could get the effect you want to work as a clipping path would be to add numerous `<circle>` elements to your `<clipPath>`.

```
<clipPath>
   <circle>
   <circle>
   <circle>
   <circle>
   ... etc ...
</clipPath>
```

But you could use a mask instead.  Masks allow patterns.

```css
.figure {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  -webkit-mask: url(#img-dotted-mask);
          mask: url(#img-dotted-mask);
  background-color: #1063B1;
}
```

```html
<p>This only works in Firefox</p>

<div class="figure"></div>

<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="img-dotted-pattern"
      viewBox="0 0 1 1"
      patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20">
      <rect width="1" height="1" fill="black"/>
      <circle cx="0.5" cy="0.5" fill="white" r="0.15"></circle>
    </pattern>

    <mask id="img-dotted-mask">
      <rect width="2000" height="2000" fill="url(#img-dotted-pattern)"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

However *inline* SVG masks applied to HTML elements, like my example above, only work in Firefox.  To get an SVG mask to work in Chrome, you would need to use `mask` or `mask-image` with an external or Data URL (as Temani has done in their answer).

Comment: Sorry. Demo is fixed now. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 3):

You can recreate the same thing using mask combined with radial-gradient

```css
.figure {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,red,#1063B1);  
                          /*radius here                           size here*/
  -webkit-mask:radial-gradient(3px, #fff 97%,transparent 100%) 0 0/20px 20px;
          mask:radial-gradient(3px, #fff 97%,transparent 100%) 0 0/20px 20px;
}


body {
  background:#f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<div class="figure"></div>
```

Or consider the SVG inside the mask property. Make sure to escape the `#` and correctly set the viewbox and width/height to have a perfect repeat

```css
.figure {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,red,#1063B1);  
  -webkit-mask:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="200" height="192" viewBox="0 0 100 90"><defs><pattern id="img-dotted-dots" x="0" y="0" height=".08" width="7.69%"><circle cx="2" cy="2" fill="white" r="0.8"></circle></pattern><mask id="img-dotted-mask"><rect width="100" height="100" fill="url(%23img-dotted-dots)"></rect></mask></defs><path d="M0 0 H 100 V 100 H 0 Z" mask="url(%23img-dotted-mask)" fill="%231063B1"></path></svg>');
          mask:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="200" height="192" viewBox="0 0 100 90"><defs><pattern id="img-dotted-dots" x="0" y="0" height=".08" width="7.69%"><circle cx="2" cy="2" fill="white" r="0.8"></circle></pattern><mask id="img-dotted-mask"><rect width="100" height="100" fill="url(%23img-dotted-dots)"></rect></mask></defs><path d="M0 0 H 100 V 100 H 0 Z" mask="url(%23img-dotted-mask)" fill="%231063B1"></path></svg>');
}


body {
  background:#f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<div class="figure"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, good solution for the question case.

Is there a solution with clip-path? I plan to use much more complex figure with pattern than the quesiton is.

Comment: @Andrii wait for the SVG wizards ;) I can only help with CSS. Updated the answer with another idea